# XML, SQLite3, parsing python

Tags: python, xml, sqlite, python-2.7

Combing MLB XML data for an entire game statistics, and I envision it moving in certain steps:

1. Taking in dates
2. Taking dates and constructing a URL to determine what games happened on those days
3. Parsing those dates for individual game ids...example (gid_2014_05_09_chnmlb_atlmlb_1)
4. Opening those game ids and parsing the XML
5. After parsing I would like to append an SQLlite database in the necessary order

Where I am stuck in pulling out individual pieces of the XML and appending a DB.
I believe URLLib2 & Elementree should enough for the parsing.

```
def get_game_id(*dates):
#construct a base url and add list dates in a loop...Date Format is ("2014_04_05")
    baseURL = 'http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_'
    for date in dates:
        year, month, day = date[0:4], date[5:7], date[8:10]
        fullurl = baseURL + year + '/month_' + month + '/day_' + day + '/'
#using the dates to find each individual game id for the date and populate a tuple
        g_id = []
        g_id = [a.text.strip()[4:-1] for a in BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(fullurl)).find_all('li',text=re.compile("gid_"))]
        db_creation
        for g in g_id:
            game_id_url = baseURL + g[0:4] + '/month_' + g[5:7] + '/day_' + g[8:10] + '/gid_' + g + '/inning/inning_all.xml'
#Actual parsing of the XML
            data = ET.parse(urllib2.urlopen(game_id_url))
            try:
                for baseball_stats in data.findall('batter'):
                    print (data.get(''))
            except:
                print None
```

Comment: Providing some example XML and the data you would like to retrieve would aid answers. :)

Comment: What do you mean by `print (data.get(''))` ?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your function at places where necessary. Give it a try

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import re
import urllib2


def get_game_id(*dates):
#construct a base url and add list dates in a loop...Date Format is ("2014_04_05")
    baseURL = 'http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_'
    for date in dates:
        year, month, day = date[0:4], date[5:7], date[8:10]
        fullurl = baseURL + year + '/month_' + month + '/day_' + day + '/'
        print fullurl
#using the dates to find each individual game id for the date and populate a tuple
        g_id = []
        g_id = [a.text.strip()[4:-1] for a in BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(fullurl)).find_all('li',text=re.compile("gid_"))]
        #db_creation
        for g in g_id:
            game_id_url = baseURL + g[0:4] + '/month_' + g[5:7] + '/day_' + g[8:10] + '/gid_' + g + '/inning/inning_all.xml'
#Actual parsing of the XML
            data = ET.parse(urllib2.urlopen(game_id_url))
            try:
                for baseball_stats in data.findall('inning/top/atbat'):
                    print baseball_stats.attrib['batter']
            except:
                print None
```